# Unexpected error when creating a SQLite database using python

Tags: python, sql, database, api

```
import json
import urllib
import sqlite3

import temp


def loading():
    url = 'https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?page=1'  # URL for API 1-5json_obj = urllib.urlopen(url)
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = json.load(response)  # loads the url and set it into data variable

    for item in data[0].keys():
        print(item)
        return data  # Get the keys


# def loading():
# print " LOADING API(s)"
# urllib.urlopen('https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?page=1')
# temp = json.dumps(data[1])
# print (json.dumps(data[1]))
# print (" ")
def createDB(data):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    # Create table
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE example
        (description text, title text, url text, company_logo text, company text, id integer primary key, company_url text, how_to_apply text,
        location text, type text, created_at timestamp)''')
    temp_values = list(tuple())
    for item in temp:

        list_of_values = [v for k, v in item.items()]
        tuple_of_values = tuple(list_of_values)
        temp_values.append(tuple_of_values)
        c.executemany('INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', temp_values)


def main():
    data = loading()
    createDB(data)


main()
```

---

I ran the code it creates the database but nothing seems to be in it this is the error I get as well File

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/issac_rodriguez/PycharmProjects/N/Sprint2/database.py", line
>   45, in 
>       main()   File "/Users/issac_rodriguez/PycharmProjects/N/Sprint2/database.py", line
>   42, in main
>       createDB(data)   File "/Users/issac_rodriguez/PycharmProjects/N/Sprint2/database.py", line
>   32, in createDB
>       for item in temp: TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

Comment: It's a typo, you go `for item in temp`, but you probably want `for item in temp_values`. This is why you should always use meaningful names instead of `x`, `temp`, etc. - `temp` is actually a meaningful name for the module (if it is the module I think it is).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the loop your `createDB()` function. You tried to iterate through `temp` which is referring to the module temp that you imported above. Perhaps you meant to iterate through `temp_values`? You may also need to pass your argument `data` into `temp_values`. Here is a potential solution:

```
temp_values = list(tuple(data))
for item in temp_values:
...
```

Hope this helps!